# java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap Error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code trying  to retrieve firebase values. My database structure is as follows:

[image]

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mystatement);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    dref = dref.child("Dog Expenditure");

    dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                HashMap<String, Object> value = (HashMap<String, Object>) child.getValue();
                String amount = value.get("amount").toString();
                String item = value.get("item").toString();
                // This will print out amount and item
                System.out.println(amount + item);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried different ways to do this but i do not just get any luck here..All i get is this error **java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap
at com.example.moses.farm.Mystatement$1.onDataChange(Mystatement.java:39)** which points to this **HashMap value = (HashMap) child.getValue();** line of code. I have been stuck here for almost a week, anyone with an idea of how to get this will truly help me

Comment: May be your child return `String` please check it...

Comment: Not sure if this will fix it, but you should definitely not cast to a HashMap. Instead cast: `Map<String, Object> value = (Map<String, Object>) child.getValue()`

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mystatement);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    dref = dref.child("Dog Expenditure");

    dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String amount = child.get("amount").toString();
                String item = value.get("item").toString();
                // This will print out amount and item
                System.out.println(amount + item);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

use this code

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap

Comment: i have noticed something very strange..in my android studio console((monitor) i see the value of a firebase entry i added manually..i.e my structurre is like this  Dog Expenditure ---KeT_eEhkkiKJYOo1hb5 -- amount: "12'000" --item: "gsgag" then i manually added a child called amount: "xxxx" still under Dog Expenditure but now without this unique identifier "KeT_eEhkkiKJYOo1hb5". The console prints out xxxx. but not the original values with a unique identifire

Comment: ok it means at least you are able to resolve type casting error right ?

Answer (score 1):

```
DatabaseReference dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
dref = dref.child("Dog Expenditure");

dref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        HashMap<String, String> value = (HashMap<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        String amount = value.get("amount");
        String item = value.get("item");
    }
    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Comment: please send me your retrieval code so i can try it with my app. i am strunded here

Answer (score 1):

```cs
HashMap<String, Object> value = child.getValue();
```

try this one

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap

Comment: @SirGeorge I didn't write the answer, karthi did. I simply removed the in-bowser snipped markup - can't help you with that.

Comment: replace object to string

Comment: @karthi java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap

Comment: HashMap<String, String> value = (HashMap<String, String>) child.getValue();

Comment: I don't know what is the problem .just remove .toString and check.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it is to first create a data model:

```
public class DogExpenditure {
    private String amount;
    private String item;

    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

Then add a ChildEventListener instead:

```
dref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        DogExpenditure dogExpenditure = dataSnapshot.getValue(DogExpenditure.class);
        System.out.println(dogExpenditure.getAmount()+dogExpenditure.getItem());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: hey  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap errror

Answer (score 0):

Change this line value.get("amount").toString();

TO

String.valueOf(value.get("amount"));
It solved my problem.

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)